# Calculating current in parallel

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits

Hypothetically, I have a circuit with a two $10\Omega$ resistors in parallel. I supply them say, $2V$. How do I calculate the current?

What if, say, the circuit now has a $10\Omega$ resistor and a  $5\Omega$ resistor in parallel with $2V$. Will anything change? I'm looking for calculations here.

Comment: Do you have any specific problems with using Ohm's Law?

Comment: Yes, I can't find out how to calculate the current in the above in parallel. I can do it for resistance and not parallel.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_connection#Resistors_2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resistors each have $10\Omega$ resistance, and they are placed in parallel. The total resistance is simply,

$$R_{T}=\left( \frac{1}{R_1} +\frac{1}{R_2}\right)^{-1}=5\Omega$$

If you supply $2V$, then the current is given by, $I=V/R_{T}=2/5 \, A$. In this case, the resistors have the same resistance, therefore the current will split evenly, i.e. the current entering either resistor is $1/5 \, A.$

---

If the scenario changes, and the resistors have $R_1=10\Omega$ and $R_2=5 \Omega$, the total resistance is,

$$R_T = \left( \frac{1}{R_1} +\frac{1}{R_2}\right)^{-1} = 10/3 \, \Omega$$

The current is once again given by, $I=V/R_T = 3/5 \, A$, which is higher than the first case. As the resistors have different resistances, the current will not split evenly. Instead, the current which enters the resistor with $R_1=10\Omega$ is given by,
$$I_1 =\frac{R_T}{R_1+R_T}I_T = 3/20 \, A$$

and applying the same formula for the second resistor yields, $I_2=9/20 \, A$ to ensure the sum of both currents is equal to the original current which entered the parallel configuration.